# How to find if a series of non-float numbers are missing in a string

Tags: bash

*In Bash*,

I want to find a range of non-float numbers in a string.

If I have a string like so:

```
"1.4.jpg 2.005.jpg 003: Blah.jpg Blah4.jpg 4.5.jpg"
```

And I want to find if numbers firstNum-lastNum are missing. Say, if

```
firstNum=1
lastNum=5
```

the function would return

"1 is missing, 2 is missing, 5 is missing"

Its relatively easy to find non-float numbers in a string, but what confuses my script is the "2.005.jpg" part of the string. My script doesnt understand how to recognize that 5 is part of float 2, and therefore should ignore it.

I would just say if the number has leading zeros or has "[0-9]." in front of it, ignore it. But unfortunately, I need support for numbers with any amount of leading zeros.

Comment: In the example of `"001.004.jpg 2.005.jpg 003.jpg Blah4.jpg"` is only 5 missing? With the example output of `"1 is missing, 2 is missing, 5 is missing"` what would example input be?

Comment: No, 1 and 2 are missing in the example because they are appended by `.004` and `.005`, respectively, and would be considered part of a float number. I only want to find numbers if they don't have `.[0-9]` extensions.

Comment: Hi @HaysLo! Welcome here! Can you write your own answer as an answer to this question? We collect good questions and answers here - so we like to collect yours!

Comment: Oh, and a friendly hint: Do not call a variable of type foo `foo` - it will bite you!

Comment: @dawg I responded to your question

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Thank you for the welcome! I only called variable of type foo `foo` because I thought it would be easier to read. But now that I think about it, i'll change it. As for the answer to my own question, I don't think I solved it yet. I came up with a better starting solution in my edit above, though.

Comment: If the filenames cannot contain space, then you could iterate over the string with a `for fname in $input`, and then test if `$fname` matches something in the form `number.number.extension`. If they do, then they are one missing element in your sequence. Otherwise you count them in.

Comment: @giusti Good solution, but the filenames in my use-case could contain spaces. I'll edit a space into the example.

Comment: Are `aa.2aa` or `aa2.aa` considered to be float numbers? In other words, in your definition, float must be of exactly this format: `<numbers>.<numbers>` and the `2s` are not floats, correct?

Comment: @PesaThe Yes, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not against using `awk`, you can use this script:

```
echo "1.4.jpg 2.005.jpg 003: Blah.jpg Blah4.jpg" | \
   awk -v min=1 -v max=5 -v RS="[^0-9. ]+" '
     ($0+0)!~/\./&&/[0-9]+/{a[$0+0]}
     END{for(i=min;i<=max;i++)if(!(i in a))print i " is missing"}'
```

This is a GNU awk script that relies on the record separator `RS` to split the line with only (float) numbers.

The trick is to add 0 to the found number and check that it is still in decimal form (without any dot `.`). If so, the number is stored in the array `a`.

The `END` statement is looping through all decimal number from `min` (1) to `max` (5) and prints a message if the number is not part of the array `a`.

The posix compliant alternative script is the following:

```
echo "1.4.jpg 2.005.jpg 003: Blah.jpg Blah4.jpg" | \
   awk -v min=1 -v max=5 '
     {
        split($0,n,"[^0-9. ]+"); 
        for(i in n){
           if((n[i]+0)!~/\./&&n[i]~/[0-9]+/){
             a[n[i]+0]
           }
        }
     }
     END{for(i=min;i<=max;i++)if(!(i in a))print i " is missing"}'
```

The main difference is the use of the function `split()` that replaces `RS`. `split` breaks the input string and puts number into the array `n`. The array elements are then checked and put in the array `a` in case of decimal number.

Comment: This works perfectly. Though I don't mind using awk, thank you for also including the posix compliant answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Answer:**

Here's a `bash` function that gives the expected output value on the provided test case in a (hopefully) reasonable way:

```
function check_missing {
    prefix=""
    for i in {1..5}; do
        # make sure that $i is present, 
        # with optional leading zeroes,
        # but with at least one non-number
        # *before* the zeroes and *after* $i
        if ! [[ "$1" =~ .*[^0-9\.]0*"$i"\.?[^0-9\.].* ]]; then 
            echo -n "${prefix}${i} is missing"
            prefix=", "
        fi
    done
    echo
}
```

I'm not sure how well this will generalize to the other inputs you have (or how important the output formatting is), but hopefully it at least gives an idea for how to solve the problem.

**Sample output:**

```
> check_missing "001.004.jpg 2.005.jpg 003.jpg Blah4.jpg"
1 is missing, 2 is missing, 5 is missing
> check_missing "1.4.jpg 2.005.jpg 003: Blah.jpg Blah4.jpg"
1 is missing, 2 is missing, 5 is missing
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is correct for the original case, but fails when the string is `1.4.jpg 2.005.jpg 003: Blah.jpg Blah4.jpg`, because it returns `3 is missing`. I think this is because your solution just works in all cases where the number you are looking for is followed by a period. Running string `001 .jpg 2: Blah.jpg` through your function would result in output `1 is missing, 2 is missing`  which is incorrect. I'll still upvote your solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [extglob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

```
find_missing() {
    shopt -s extglob

    for(( i = $2; i <= $3; i++ )); do
        [[ $1 = !(*[0-9]|*[0-9].)*(0)"$i"!(.[0-9]*|[0-9]*) ]] || printf '<%s> missing!\n' "$i"
    done
}
```

*Consider `$i` to be 4:*

- `"$i"`: match the number
- `"$i"!(.[0-9]*|[0-9]*)`: match the number if it's not followed by either `.<number>`, which would make it a float number (`4.1` for example), or simply followed by another number which would make it a different number (it would falsely consider `41` to be `4` for example)
- `*(0)"$i"!(.[0-9]*|[0-9]*)`: allow leading 0s
- `!(*[0-9]|*[0-9].)*(0)"$i"!(.[0-9]*|[0-9]*)`: match the number if it's not prefixed by `<number>.`, which would make it a float number (`1.4` for example), or prefixed by another number which would make it a different number (it would falsely consider `24` to be `4` for example)
- `shopt -s extglob`: enable [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

---

**Test run:**

```
$ find_missing "1.4.jpg 2.005.jpg 003: Blah.jpg Blah4.jpg" 1 5
<1> missing!
<2> missing!
<5> missing!  
$ find_missing "1.4.jpg 2.005.jpg 003: Blah.jpg Blah4.jpg" 1 2
<1> missing!
<2> missing!
$ find_missing "001 3.002 A.4A" 1 4
<2> missing!
<3> missing!
```